# View Image array from web folder in iOS

Tags: ios, xcode

I want to be able to view images from a web folder inside my iPhone app. I know how to view the images with a specific url (i.e. www.mywebsite.com/image.jpg). That's easy. I just don't know how to asynchronously load an array. Basically I need to view images with a specific sequence (i.e. mywebsite.com/image_001.jpg, image_002.jpg, image_003.jpg, etc). There may be 10 or 100 images in a folder with that sequence. How do I let my app load images with a sequence?

Comment: are these images in document directory of app or are they in NSBundle of app?

Comment: Can you tell me how images are named are they named as image_001, image_002, image_003,...

Comment: That will vary. I have a desktop application that sends photos to a web folder with a specific image name (i.e. image_001.jpg, etc). There may be times that I have 10 images being uploaded or times where there are 1000.

Comment: But your image number always starts after <imageName>_<number>.jpg. Is this format you have

Comment: Yes. That is correct

Comment: I have posted my answer. Let me know if any issue.

Answer (score 0):

Following code will sort images of this file format  "imageName_number.jpg"

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *webDir=[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"WebFolder"];
    NSFileManager *filemgr;


    NSMutableArray *fileNum;
    fileNum=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];


    filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    //This will give all files of your web directory you can uncomment to get dynamically
    //NSArray *filelist = [filemgr contentsOfDirectoryAtPath: webDir error: nil];
    // this is just example shows how unsorted will be used to sort image no you can comment this line
    NSArray *filelist=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"abc_001.jpg",@"def_005.jpg",@"abc_002.jpg",@"abc_0103.jpg",@"abc_0010.jpg",@"abc_008.jpg", nil];
   int count = (int)[filelist count];

  NSMutableDictionary *dictFileNumWithPath=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

   NSString *imageSeprator=@"_";

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++){
        NSString *imageName=[filelist objectAtIndex: i];
        if (!([imageName rangeOfString:imageSeprator].location == NSNotFound)) {

            NSRange startRange = [imageName rangeOfString:imageSeprator];
            NSRange endRange = [imageName rangeOfString:@".jpg"];

            NSRange searchRange = NSMakeRange( startRange.location+1, endRange.location-endRange.length);
            NSString *strNum= [imageName substringWithRange:searchRange];

            NSString *webPath=[webDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:imageName];
            [dictFileNumWithPath setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[strNum intValue]] forKey:webPath];

        }
    }

    NSArray *sortedKeysFilePathArray =
    [dictFileNumWithPath keysSortedByValueUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];

    NSLog(@"%@", sortedKeysFilePathArray);
```